# sql azure management portal adding keys

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We migrated our mysql database onto sql azure. Logged in to the sql azure management portal. I can see the tables and add columns etc but was not able to figure out how to view existing foreign key constraints on a field (or a way to add foreign key constraints using the UI). 
Just curious as to whether this is supported in the UI? Or should we install SQL Server Management studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't see constraints or relationships using the SQL Azure Management Portal. I suggest you use SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2. The express edition works fine:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593

However, even using Management Studio you don't get the full designer support, but you can at least see the foreign keys.